# How do I turn my USB light off but still have it feed information to my headphones?

Tags: usb

I've been trying to see how to turn off the light on my USB stick and still have it work, it is used for my blue-tooth headphones and the light is really annoying and gives me a headache.

Comment: Protip: Technical questions require technical details. When asking a question like this, always include the make and model of the devices in question (PC, dongle, and headphones). With information like that, we might be able to, say, discover that your PC has a built-in Bluetooth radio so you don't need the dongle at all. Or maybe we'll discover that your headphones aren't Bluetooth at all, but use a different wireless audio standard that we could recommend a different compatible dongle for, which doesn't have the light. Always include as much relevant technical info as you can.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the technical details of the USB dongle you're using to wirelessly stream audio to your headphones, there's no way for us to know if there's a way to turn off the light through software. Consider covering up the light with a bit of black electrical tape (that stuff tends to be completely opaque), or if you're handy with a soldering iron, consider opening up the dongle and removing the LED. You may or may not need to replace it with a (non-light-emitting) diode with similar electrical characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, That light just informs a connection (or power), I would assume it is a hardware or firmware coded, I could be wrong. But I think tape might do the trick.